# Trying to set width of a div using width of viewport do not work

Tags: html, css, angular

I have tried to set font-size with the help of width of the viewport and want to set the size of 20% of the viewports size by using

```
h4{
  font-size: 20vw;
}
```

But the font-size that it sets is huge. Maybe 30 times bigger than supposed to. Have I missed something? When I tested from a tutorial [Tryit Editor v3.6](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_unit_vw) it worked like supposed to so I have no idea what can go wrong.

Example: By using window.innerWidth I got a viewport-size of 1229px and 13vn of that should make a text fit in a textfield of 160px as I understand it.

Comment: `vn` is not a unit - Either `vh` or `vw`...I'm assuming you meant `vw`.

Comment: did you mean `em` instead of `vn`?

Comment: Assuming vn is a typo, 1vw is 1 percent of the width of the viewport, so if the viewport is 1229px wide, 20vw would make for a font-size of 246px. But why are you writing 20vw if you want 13vw?

Comment: Sorry. Misspelled. I have used vw in my code.

Comment: The example is just how I calculated not the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `vw` instead, it stands for ('viewport width'). Also, `vw` is quite a big number, define the font as something like:

> ```
> h4 {
>   font-size: 1vw;
> }
> ```

If the font is still too big, use '0.x' values. And if the font gets too small at some point, use the CSS's `@media` to define a minimum size, like this:

> `@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
>    h4 {
>         font-size: 12px;
>       }`

That'll make the page follow this command only if the screen is small enough.

Comment: It is vw I meant. But I think I have used vw in a wrong way. I that that 20vw mean that the textmessage for example would be set to fill out  20 percent of the viewport

Comment: Ah, no, the font-size is not the same as the width of any given text. If it would be, all the lines in any block of text would be different sizes.

Comment: @Mikael then you can set a cointainer for 20% width of the vw, and fit the font to it. Use this for reference: https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/

Comment: Thanks for advice. I think this is the best sollution for me